# Qual a maneira correta de usar AWS iot.describeCertificate()? Não consigo acessar a função de maneira assíncrona

Tags: node.js, expressões-lambda, amazon-aws, assincronismo

Preciso recuperar o status de um certificado no AWS-IoT-Core usando uma função Lambda com NodeJS.
Segundo a [documentação oficial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Iot.html#describeCertificate-property) precisaria usar a função `describeCertificate()`.

Esse é o código que estou usando para testes:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const iot = new AWS.Iot()
let cert = {}

async function descCert (params) {

  console.log("start descCert")
  console.log("params")
  console.log(params)

  await iot.describeCertificate(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log('describeCertificate - Fn')
    if (err) {
      console.log('describeCertificate - Error')
      return console.log(err, err.stack)
    }else{
      console.log('describeCertificate - data')
      cert = data
      return console.log(data)
    }
    console.log("end describeCertificate - Fn")
  })

  console.log("end descCert")
}

module.exports.testFn = async (event, context, callback) => { 

    var zzz = {
        certificateId: 'xxxx8c0891f8xxxxxx'
    }
    await descCert(zzz)
    console.log("after descCert")
    console.log(cert)

...
}
```

Acho que o erro aqui é como estou usando essa função com o NodeJS pois os pontos de controle dentro de `await iot.describeCertificate( ...` não estão aparecendo no `CloudWatch`.

Eu estava esperando ver essa sequencia:

1. start descCert
2. params
3. {certificateId: 'xxxx8c0891f8xxxxxx'}
4. describeCertificate - Fn
5. Ou describeCertificate - Error OU describeCertificate - data
6. os dados mesmo
7. end describeCertificate - Fn
8. end descCert
9. after descCert
10. os dados mesmo

Mas o que estou recebendo é essa sequência:

1. start descCert
2. params
3. {certificateId: 'xxxx8c0891f8xxxxxx'}
4. end descCert
5. after descCert
6. os dados mesmo //{}

Os passos de 4 a 7 não aparecem no log, ou seja, a função não está sendo chamada.

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const iot = new AWS.Iot()
let cert = {}

descCert = async (params) => {

  console.log("start descCert")
  console.log("params")
  console.log(params)

  try {
    const data = await iot.describeCertificate(params).promise(); 
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('erro fn descCert');
    throw new Error(e.message);  }

}

module.exports.testFn = async (event, context, callback) => { 

    const zzz = {
        certificateId: 'xxxx8c0891f8xxxxxx'
    }
    try {
      const cert = await descCert(zzz)
      console.log("after descCert")
      console.log(cert)
      return cert
    } catch(e) {
       console.log(e)
    }



}
```